# Can someone help find out written 19th century French?

Tags: correspondance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGogR.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpGZp.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/klKm9.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVeoR.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/emmqT.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6a9T.jpg

Hello. I need help with these documents, I need to understand what is written here. I would be grateful if you understand at least some words.
I am not asking for a translation of the text, I am asking you to understand what is written in French

Comment: Sorry to inform you that this type of question is not allowed. No text translation. Explanations can be asked about very short sentences, phrases and of course words. Translation of very short sentences and phrases from a foreign language are allowed, specially from English, but nothing else. All translation from French to English is forbidden. however such problems might be solved sometimes using the chat (Chez Causette).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for explanation of text.

Comment: I am still learning about these sites, and I did not know this was not allowed. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: There's no translation involved that I can see, and a good knowledge of historical French can help decipher this document and vice versa. I think it's okay to let the question develop and see if anything interesting comes of it. You can undelete your answer if you like.

Comment: LPH, I am not asking for a translation of the text, I am asking you to understand what is written in French

Comment: @fwf34453 I'm trying to, but unfortunately, I can't read a single word.

Comment: The combination of bad image quality + unclear handwriting + probably outdated language + absence of context makes it almost impossible to even just reproduce what is written there...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not an OCR service

Comment: Laurent S. you can just walk by, maybe someone else can help me

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request to transcribe an image of unspecified origin and this cannot possibly help anyone else. (In contrast, a question asking about the transcription of a clearly identified manuscript that other people might wonder about could be suitable for this site.)

Comment: @fwf34453 > Maybe you can just walk by yourself and go to any online forum instead... I understand you're new to SE community, but please first read a bit about the rules of each community to know whether your question is welcome here or not, or at least don't take it personally when people make the remark. I would suggest reading the [How to ask?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @fwf34453 Why not put your question to the chat instead? I'm sure there'll be people willing to help you.

Comment: Laurent S. You can't help me so you can walk by, what's wrong ? There is a person who helped me a lot, and if you have nothing to say about the case then keep quiet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing some context about these documents might help figuring out what some missing parts are, might also broaden the interest of your question and thus reduce the reluctance to accept it some users expressed.

Anyway, here is an attempt for the first document:

[image]

> Vous comprendrez sans doute cher ami, qu'il ne nous reste (en Crimée?) que de jouer ce double rôle dans l'état déplorable ou nous nous trouvons à Petersbourg, et il me parait qu'on y est entièrement (attendus?) pour les (finances/femmes?), et que même la question d'incompétence commence a inquiéter fortement le gouvernement, qui ne trouve pas les moyens de la terminer convenablement. Venu de bien loin je n'entend certainement que des bruits éloignés, aussi je ne peux rien dire positivement, mais arrivé à Petersbourg, je m'empresserai de vous faire part avec le premier courrier de toutes mes observations.

Another one ends with:

> Département de basses Pyrénées.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you so much !

Comment: Essai : en ? *Crimée/Ĉhine?* —  Petersbourg (surtout avec le second) — entièrement ? *attesté/attelé* ? — *femmes/fermiers* (pas de point pour le f*i*…) — ? *d'imassé/incassée jalouse/p[a|e]leuse* (Pb du point avant le ‘p’) ?

Comment: @Personne Bonnes observations, merci !

Comment: unfortunately I have no other information about these documents, otherwise I would gladly provide it to users

Comment: Where did you find them and why do you want to be able to specifically read them?

Comment: @jlliagre est ce que vous êtes parvenus a transcrire ce texte simplement avec vos yeux ?

Comment: @SkyLand Oui, mais ça n'a pas été immédiat... Il faut essayer d'imaginer ce que peuvent être les mots qu'on n'arrive pas à déchiffrer. J'ai un peu l'habitude de lire des documents d'état civil dans le cadre de recherches généalogiques et ça aide bien.